# Are we being invaded?

Tags: discussion

In this question: [criticism of down-voting for question?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38369/criticism-of-down-voting-for-question)

There are no less than four accounts, all created today, all with let's just call them "congruent" points of view.

Perhaps I'm cynical, but to me they smell of sock puppet.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they are socks, but please don't feed the trolls, just flag and move on.

*the question vanishes in a puff of smoke*

Comment: Thanks for deleting.